# Minimum product quantity with a sample

Tags: quantity, sample

I have a store for printed invitations that has a minimum order of 30 on most products, but there needs to be an option for individual samples too.

I've seen quite a few tutorials for sample buttons and also know how to set minimum order quantities for each product, but I'm not sure if these can be combined, particularly as the sample button will essentially add a quantity of 1 to the cart.

Does anyone know if this is possible or have ideas for a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your product has a minimum quantity of 30 to be ordererd, it is not possible to order 1.

But what you can do is:

1. Create a second product, which is the same
2. Set a maximim qty of 1 on the product
3. link them somehow
4. Add a button to add the sibling product

The alterntive:

- Dont add a maximum
- Implement the check by yourself
- add an observer, so when a sample is added, it is flagged
- when a product is flagged, only one can be ordered and the minimum check doesn't happen

Comment: Hi Fabian, thaks for your response! I think the alternative product is a great approach, how would you link the products?

Comment: I would either use a sku which is the same+suffix or create an attribute which holds the other product id